# chrome webdriver cannot open new tab

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open up a new tab in Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="2.21.0.0"  but it doesn't open anything, however if I move the debug tracking step back to the line "body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't')" to rerun the second time, it works ??

```
  var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
  IWebElement body = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("body")));                          
                            Thread.Sleep(2000);
                            body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');
```

Update:  It seems to put a stop on chrome, it does open the tab properly. So instead of using Thread.sleep, just try:

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
 js.ExecuteScript("return window.stop");
 body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a new tab with Chrome:

```
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

    // open a new tab and set the context
    driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('_blank', 'tab2');");
    driver.SwitchTo().Window("tab2");

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: thanks, I used to use the same method, and yes this so far the only way I can get feature to work

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for your problem :

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"t").build().perform();
```

Comment: are you sure this is for C# ?